# How to decrypt Express.js Connect.sid cookie

Tags: javascript, express

here is my cookies
connect.sid:s:fRptL0_o-5FBbqqbDluHrSvo4DyKHvcP.6Y57+JkukcncVD/6ANbtojCGkL2yLnnmJgo2n30SnWo

the secret is #@%#&^$^$%@$^$&%#$%@#$%$^%&$%^#$%@#$%#E%#%@$FEErfgr3g#%GT%536c53cc6%5%tv%4y4hrgrggrgrgf4n

i tried decoding it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to decode.

The value is *signed*, not encrypted. The secret is only used to *verify* it.

It uses [the cookie-signature module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-signature) to do this.